# iff and imply precendence, which is more priveleged

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I encounter an equation.

$A \leftrightarrow C \rightarrow D$

I want to ask the above equation means

1. $(A \leftrightarrow C) \rightarrow D$

or

2. $A \leftrightarrow (C \rightarrow D)$.

Which is more priveleged?

Thanks.

Comment: They are both the same

Comment: $A\leftrightarrow C\to D \;$ means $\; (A\leftrightarrow C) \land (C\to D) \;\;\;\;$

Comment: So if they are same precendence. Can I say it should be (A ↔ C) → D?

Comment: why A↔C→D means (A↔C)∧(C→D), I cannot understand, do you have some webpage that I can read? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple operators bind to the same phrases:

$(A \iff B) \implies C$

This means that whenever $A$ and $B$ are equivalent statements, $C$ is true. You might talk about conjectures this way. Suppose $B \implies C$ is already known, but $B$ isn't known to be true. Then if $A$ is known to be true, $A \iff B$ would imply $C$. For example, consequences of $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$ are of this form.

$A \iff (B \implies C)$

This means that $A$ is true if and only if it's true that $B$ implies $C$. For example, $\forall A, A \iff (\neg A \implies \mathrm{False})$ says that every true statement $A$ can be proven by contradiction.

$A \iff B \implies C$

This means that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent statements, and that $B$ implies $C$. Since this interpretation doesn't depend on which subphrase is interpreted first, we could say they are of the same precedence. This binding is common for relations.

Answer (score 0):

The most common case is to see two or more expressions equated. For instance, you will see the phrase "the following are equivalent", suggesting that A iff B iff C etc for a list of propositions A, B, and C.

As Loki said, they seem to be equivalent under the assumption you have access to the law of excluded middle. Even so, it feels incredibly awkward to talk about "if two statements are equivalent, a third follows".